# Multiple AJAX requests using the same ajax_object.ajaxurl

Tags: ajax

I have a plugin that makes different AJAX calls, using the `ajax_object.ajaxurl`. Both AJAX requests are coded in the same file (emx-functions.js). It seems, however, that only one AJAX call is successfully firing. Am I limited to using the `ajaxurl` for only a single AJAX request, or can I configure all my AJAX requests with the same `ajaxurl`. I presume that the reason the other AJAX call isn't working is due to a conflict, as they are both using the same `ajaxurl`. Is that correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Here's how I'm setting up AJAX:

```
function load_ajax_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( "emx-functions", plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'emx-functions.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  wp_localize_script( 'emx-functions', 'EMX', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'load_ajax_scripts');
```

Here's the code from the emx-functions.js file:

```
function disable_forms_ajax(){

  var disable;

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // if checkbox checked
    if( jQuery('input[name="all_fields_or_not[]"]:visible:checked').length == 1 ){
      $disable = 'true';
      // take this out
      alert('checked');
    } else {
      $disable = 'false';
      // take this out
      alert('unchecked');
    }

        // get ticket_id
    $ticket_id = jQuery('[value="Save Coupons"]:visible')
                .parent()
                .parent()
                .children('input:first').val();

    var data = {
      action: 'hidden_form_fields',
      ticket_id: $ticket_id,
      disable: $disable
    };

    jQuery.post(EMX.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
      alert(response);
    });
    return false;
  });
}

function available_coupons_ajax(){

    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

      // get ticket_id
      $ticket_id = jQuery('[value="Save Coupons"]:visible')
                  .parent()
                  .parent()
                  .children('input:first').val();

      // get checked coupon elements
      $coupon_els = jQuery('input.button[value="Save Coupons"]')
                      .closest('form[name="ticket-coupons"]:visible')
                      .find('input:checked');

      // convert to array and get coupon codes
      $coupon_codes = Array.prototype.slice.call($coupon_els).map(function(el){
        return el.value.toLowerCase();
      });

      // prepare ajax call
      var data = {
        action: 'set_ticket_coupon_availability',
        ticket_id: $ticket_id,
        coupon_codes: $coupon_codes
      };

      // ajax call
      jQuery.post(EMX.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
      });
      return false;
    });

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show `emx-functions.js` file code

Comment: @WPTC-Troop added

Answer (score 1):

To clarify your doubt you localized variable will contains the same values until it is overriden.

In your case `EMX.ajaxurl` will be available throught the script. Ajax not happening at your intended event might be due to not executing the ajax function but **definetly not due to** `EMX.ajaxurl`. `EMX.ajaxurl` will contain the ajax url.

`EMX.ajaxurl` can be used for multiple times unless it is overriden. So I guess you are not calling you ajax function at the intended time correctly. You need to execute `disable_forms_ajax(), available_coupons_ajax()` whenever you wanted to make the ajax. Also please make sure is there any script error that prevents from making ajax.